# Cin >> reading input

Tags: c++, xcode

When I input "M12 9UB" to this code:

```
std::string postal_code;

cout << "Enter postal code: ";
cin >> postal_code;
cout << "Your postal code is: " << postal_code << endl;
```

The output is "Your postal code is: M12".

So how do I get `cin` to read the whole line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) to read a whole line from a stream:

```
std::getline(std::cin, postal_code);
```

[Live example.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bc8f1b94fe6f42c9)

Answer (score 0):

You may use the C++ getline function like so:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    std::string postal_code;

    cout << "Enter postal code: ";
    getline(cin,postal_code);
    cout << "Your postal code is: " << postal_code << endl;
}
```